# Change directory path of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a website and on one of the pages I have a several `GridViews`. I have a requirement where each `GridView` will show different files from different directory. I can get the files and view them in the `GridView` but can't seem to figure out how I would go about changing the directory path for each grid. this is what I have so far

```
public class FileDetails
{
public string FileName { get; set; }
public string FullPath { get; set; }
}

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/document/Generic/"));
    List<FileDetails> files = new List<FileDetails>();
    foreach(string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        files.Add(new FileDetails()
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            FullPath = filePath,
        });
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = files;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

How would I implement the above code to change the directory path for `GridView2, GridView3 and GridView4`.

Thanks in advance for all your help and support

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method which accepts a string argument for directory name and returns a gridview some thing like below :

```
public GridView BindMyGrid(string directoryName)
{

// Declare GridView grd = new GridView()

  //fetch the files from directory

  //set grd.DataSource

  //return grd

}
```

and you can call this method to set different grids as

```
GridView grid1 = BindMyGrid("directory1")
GridView grid2 = BindMyGrid("directory2")
GridView grid3 = BindMyGrid("directory3")
```

Comment: I got it working I changed it so it returns a `List<T>` Thanks for your help